# Proving that this pair of series' can only be satisfied with infinitely many terms.

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, divergent-series

I'm trying to prove that the following pair of series can only be satisfied if we have infinitely many coefficients.

$$k^2 = \sum_{n=1}^{M} a_n k^n \text{ ,} $$
$$ k^3 = \sum_{n=1}^{M} (-1)^na_n k^n $$

where $k$ is a positive integer.

Comment: what about $M=2$ and $a_1=0$ and $a_2=1$ for the first sum?

Comment: I need them both to be simultaneously satisfied -- but otherwise, that works.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to also exclude the $k=1$ case.

Let $k=1$ and let

$$a_n=\begin{cases}
0&\text{ for }n\text{ odd}\\
\frac{1}{j-1}&\text{ for }n\text{ even and }M=2j-1\text{ odd}\\
\frac{1}{j}&\text{ for }n\text{ even and }M=2j\text{ even}
\end{cases}$$

Then if $M=2j-1$, each $a_n=\frac{1}{j-1}$ and

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{2j-1} a_n k^n=\frac{1}{j-1}(1^2+1^4+\cdots+1^{2j-2})=1=1^2 $$

And also

$$\sum_{n=1}^{2j-1} (-1)^na_n k^n=\frac{1}{j-1}(1^2+1^4+\cdots+1^{2j-2})=1=1^3 $$

If $M=2j$ then

$$ \sum_{n=1}^{2j} a_n k^n=\frac{1}{j}(1^2+1^4+\cdots+1^{2j})=1=1^2 $$

and

$$\sum_{n=1}^{2j} (-1)^na_n k^n=\frac{1}{j}(1^2+1^4+\cdots+1^{2j})=1=1^3 $$

Comment: That's a good point -- I'll have to exclude k = 1. Thanks for the insight!

Comment: You're welcome.